# Get QThread that created QObject

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

Some `QThread * worker` has created `QObject *tmp = new QObject()`. How can another thread identify the `worker` given `tmp`? Is there something like:

`QThread *answer = tmp->getThreadThatCreatedThisObject();`

Comment: It'd be useful to know why you insist on knowing those threads? If the creating thread spins an event loop (it should!), then you can invoke `deleteLater` on that object from any thread and it's safe. The deletion will be carried out in the proper thread's event loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`QObject::thread()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#thread):

```
QThread* answer = tmp->thread();
```